# Hunspell Max word length

Tags: hunspell, nhunspell

I'm using Nhunspell to check some spelling and found that :

iamtheverrymoddelofthemoddlemajorgeneralImmineraryhjkfdhgjkfdhgjkdfhgjkdfhgjkdfhgjkdfhgukhdfgiuhruihgtuibtgiurtguitigubuitiuunguirureuinbuivbnbuivbniugndukghdfghuierbnuigvbgiutbiudb

is an English word. Even chromes spell checker agrees. Does anyone know why this is accepted? Seems to be some kind of max length?